# Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported) node-canvas

Tags: node.js, canvas

I am trying to use node-canvas to crop a background image and i am running into some a weird error with the following code.

The error is "[Error: error while writing to output stream]". If i use the crop example code from the node-canvas repo i get this error "Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)"

```js
/* */
var cnv = new Canvas(w,h),
    ctx = cnv.getContext('2d'),
    original  = '/img/pages/'+page+'/background.jpg';


ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;



fs.readFile('public/'+original, function( err,image){
  if (err) {
    res.status(404)
        .send('Not found');
  }
  else {
    var 
    img     = new Image;
    img.src = image;


    ctx.drawImage(img, 
      Math.abs( (w-img.width)/2),0,
      w,h,
      0,0,
      w,h
    );


    cnv.toBuffer(function(err, buf){

      console.log(err);

      if( err){
        res.status(500)
            .send('Error generating image buffer');
      }
      else {
        fs.writeFile('public'+resampled, buf, function(err){

          console.log(err);
          console.log('Resized and saved in %dms', new Date - start);

          returnResampledFile( res,page,w,h);

        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I've used node-canvas several times with no issues but for some reason this is a problem. any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`libjpeg` (which is probably used under the hood) doesn't support DNL markers in JPEG files ([see this document, towards the end, for an explanation](http://libjpeg.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libjpeg/libjpeg/structure.doc?revision=1.1&content-type=text%2Fplain)). Files which contains such markers will declare to be of zero height (hence the `Empty JPEG image` message). My guess would be your input file uses such markers, triggering an error.

As for solutions: try and find a JPEG reader that will read these types of files and can convert them back to something that libjpeg can handle. I'm afraid I can't recommend anything as I've never run into this problem myself.

Comment: thanks for your reply. thats what i thought at first but after some fiddling it turned out to be my issue.

In the line where i initialized the canvas instance, width and height were set from a query string and were still parsed as strings so the canvas probably was initailized with a 0,0 width and height. once i use a proper number/ int it all works fine now. some better error handling or type conversion might help. i will suggest that to the node-canvas team repo.

var cnv = new Canvas(w,h);

Comment: Did you generate a 0-height JPEG by mistake perhaps? That might trigger the same message I guess :)

Comment: ya thats exactly what it was.

Comment: FYI document link is broken.

Comment: As @JovanAlleyne mentioned, same happened with me. Variables (width and height)  passed for `Canvas` initialization were undefined and error thrown was same "Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)".