# How to check that jpeg file contains DNL marker with nodejs?

Tags: c++, node.js, opencv

In my application I use opencv bindings for nodejs. Few days ago it starts crashing on some files with error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -10 (Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)) in throwOnEror file
/home/.../opencv/src/modules/highgui/src/grfmt_base.cpp, line 131
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
```

How to check that file contains DNL marker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported) node-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470268/empty-jpeg-image-dnl-not-supported-node-canvas)

Comment: It seems you already found one -- call `imread`, catch `cv::Exception` and see if the error message is like what you see above. :) Otherwise either implementing a JPEG parser, or finding a library that supports DNL (i.e. something other than libjpeg), its bindings for node.js, and using that instead of `imread`. | The more interesting question may be where are those wonky images coming from? It would be good to know the real source of the problem.